# How to get short-lived access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

I saw the page about "Removal of offline_access permission" https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ 
   but I can't find a way to let the access token expire to test my desktop app. When I log in I only can get an accesstoken with 2 month. 
    How can I make an accesstoken expire in short time? How can I get a short-lived access token?

Answer (score 2):

I guess, that if you will use Graph API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer you will get short –lived token (should expire in 1 -2 hours). Then copy it and use it in your application for testing.

Also I have found this link where you can test access token and find out who issued, when it will expire and some more: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token